# Set-up animation time in paraview from one column

Tags: time, paraview

I have a `.txt` file containing columns of data. At each row, i have 5 columns, containing object id, time, x position, y position, z position.

Example:

```
    ID Time X Y Z
    0  0    0 0 0
    1  0    1 0 0
    3  0    0 1 0
    0  1    0 0 0
    1  1    0 1 0
```

I don't know how to set up Paraview to read the column `Time` as the Time in the animation. 
I know it's possible with multiple files (one for each time step), but is it possible with one single file containing all the time steps as shown above ?

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not supported in ParaView (last release 5.6.0) by default, but it should be quite easy to do it with a live programmable source.